# Swift Protocol Inheritance Doesn't compile

Tags: swift, inheritance, protocols

Was trying out some different things with Protocl Inheritance in swift when I came upon an issue where it doesn't compile as it claims "Parent does not conform to BaseParent" even though I can't for the life of me understand why. Probably a back to basics moment...
Anyway, here is an explanation and the code:

```
/*
 - To conform to 'BaseParent', you must have a var called 'child' that conforms to 'BaseChild'
 - 'Child' conforms to 'BaseChild'
 - 'Parent' has a property called 'child' which must conform to 'Child' and by extension, 'BaseChild'
 - Therefore, any element assigned to 'child', must conform to 'BaseChild'
 - Therefore, 'Parent' has a var called 'child' that conforms to 'BaseChild'
 - So why does 'Parent' not conform to 'BaseParent'
*/

protocol BaseChild { /* some methods */ }
protocol Child : BaseChild { /* some more methods */ }

protocol BaseParent {
    var child : BaseChild! {get set}
}

class Parent : BaseParent {
    var child : Child!
}
```

Probably some obvious reason about protocols that I'm missing but if anyone can go into more details I'd appreciate it :)

Comment: The getter is OK as you are returning an object that conforms to `BaseChild` protocol, but the setter doesn't match. You cannot set any object conforming `BaseChild` as expected in `BaseParent`, it expects any object conforming to `Child` protocol.

Comment: Of course, makes sense. Add it as the answer and I'll accept it when it lets me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The getter of `child` declared in `Parent` is OK as it returns an object that conforms to `BaseChild!` (because `Child` inherits from `BaseChild`). But the setter doesn't conform to the declaration of the parent, as it expects **any** object that conforms to `BaseChild` protocol, but you are overriding to expect **only** those that also conform to `Child` protocol.

As a workaround to keep type safety, you can create a wrapper property in `Parent` class:

```
protocol BaseChild { /* some methods */ }
protocol Child : BaseChild { /* some more methods */ }

protocol BaseParent {
    var baseChild : BaseChild! {get set}
}

class Parent : BaseParent {
    var baseChild: BaseChild!
    var child : Child! {
        get { return baseChild as! Child }
        set { baseChild = newValue }
    }
}
```